# Accessing parents' relationships from childrens models

Tags: python, django, inheritance

In a Django project, I'd like to basically represent a city environment: a couple of buildings and streets with the possibility to move between them.  In order to achieve that, I picked the [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)) representation: each *node* represents a room or a piece of road, and each *edge* represents the possibility to travel between two nodes.

So I have a first app `graphs` with the following `Graph`, `Node` and `Edge` models:

```
class Graph(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Node(models.Model):
    graph = models.ForeignKey(Graph)

    # some methods

class Edge(models.Model):
    node_a = models.ForeignKey(Node, related_name='node_a')
    node_b = models.ForeignKey(Node, related_name='node_b')

    # some methods
```

On top of these abstract concepts, I'd like to build more concrete ones: the graph is actually a map, a node can ben a street or a room with defined coordinates in the map, and an edge symbolizes a path between two nodes.  In a second `cities` app, I basically have:

```
from graphs.models import *

class Map(Graph):
    # ...

class Element(Node):
    # ...

class Path(Edge):
    # ...
```

This is where inheritance comes in the way and where I'm losing myself with Django model relations.

1/ I'd like to enrich the existing `ForeignKey` between `Element` and `Map` to add coordinates (x, y), because an element has a specific place in the space of a map.  But I'm not sure it's possible.  Should I define a new relation (like [it's been done here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695458/django-model-inheritance-and-relationships)) ?  Wouldn't it be terrible in terms of architecture ?  And if it is the thing to do, how can I add extra data (i.e. the coordinates) to this relation ?  (I know about [m2m-through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships), I don't need a m2m relation is what I need here).

2/ Through inheritance, an `Element` (which is a `Node`) belongs to a `Map` (which is a `Graph`), but obviously I can't do this:

```
>>> map = Map.objects.get(id=1)  # suppose it exists and has a few Elements
>>> map_elements = map.element_set().all()

AttributeError: 'Map' object has no attribute 'element_set'
```

Is there a way I can tell Django to use the `Map`'s parent `node_set` to find its elements ?

Or maybe am I going the wrong way and should drop this whole inheritance idea ?  I quite like it because it allows me to keep all the logic bound to graphs manipulation in a different app.

Comment: My current assumption: I'll have to re-define FK between `Map` and `Element`, probably with an intermediate `Location` model, holding the coordinates...

Comment: What do you need the "graphs" model classes for ?

Comment: I mainly use it to put methods such as `count_nodes/edges`, and this is also the object I give to my renderer to obtain a representation of it.

Comment: I mean: do you have a concrete use case for these model classes except being inherited by your `Map`, `Element` and `Path` (and failing to match your needs at this point) ? Your "renderer" shouldn't care about the concrete types as long as what you pass implements the required interface...

Comment: Not especially; the `Graph` is basically a simple collection of `Node` objects.

Comment: Then just ditch the whole 'graphs' thing and directly implement what you need in your real models. If you later find out you could reuse parts of the implementation somewhere else it will be time to factor it out (BTW remember that Python supports multiple inheritance so you can factor out behaviour to a "mixin" class).

Comment: Yep you are right: I was going the wrong direction with this inheritance thing.  Thanks for the heads up ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way I would do it, which can truly describe any collection of connected or disconnected graphs. Only problem you have with that set up is nothing prevents you from connecting two nodes from different graphs, which should be an error.

```
class Graph(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Node(models.Model):
    graph = models.ForeignKey(Graph)
    x = models.IntegerField()
    y = models.IntegerField()
    neighbors = models.ManyToMayField('self')
```

You don't need an actual Edge Model, unless you are also trying to describe directional graphs. In Which case it would be:

```
class Graph(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Node(models.Model):
    graph = models.ForeignKey(Graph)
    x = models.IntegerField()
    y = models.IntegerField()

class Edge(models.Model):
    start = models.ForeignKey(Node, related_name='start_node_set')
    end = models.ForeignKey(Node, related_name='end_node_set')
```

You are correct, in this case, forget about inheritance, that is a very wrong place to use it.
Also if you would like to visualize graphs on the actual map, recommend using Google Maps and GeoDjango. But that's a separate subject :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time reading and answering this.  I've been exploring the m2m solution you are talking about (a good read on the subject: [Self-referencing many-to-many through](https://charlesleifer.com/blog/self-referencing-many-many-through/)) but came back to a more simple implementation afterward.  I suppose I'll just drop the inheritance crazyness then, and leave the `graph` app alone.